# Custom counter inside ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can not initialize custom counter and reset it inside **ng-repeat** directive. I have a colors array with three item

```
$scope.colors=['color1','color2','color3']
```

My colors array length is 2. I want to bind class in my ng-repeat list colors array 0 to 2 length. When it reach max of it's length then reset it to 0 and again repeat. I can implement it other place like php,jquery etc but i can't implement it on angular view.

```
<!-- single cat -->
        <div ng-repeat="cat in contacts|filter:search.name">
              <div class="item item-divider">
                {{cat.name}} <span class="badge badge-positive">{{cat.data.length}}</span>
              </div>

              <!-- cat contact single -->
              <a class="item" href="#" ng-repeat="p in cat.data">
                <h2 class="letter colors[customerCounterIndex]">{{p.name.charAt(0)}}</h2>
                  <span class="name">{{p.name}}</span>
                  <p>{{p.phone}}</p>
              </a>
              <!-- end cat contact single -->
        </div>
        <!-- end single cat -->
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for ngClass: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass ?

Comment: I can use ng-class but i can't init the custom counter and reset it inside my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, `<h2 class="letter" ng-class="colors[$index % colors.length]">`